# Можно ли получить название активного приложения?

Tags: android, android-service

Пишу сервис который должен получать название активного приложения, и сохранять его, как это можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле есть решение, работающее с 4 и до 6 версии включительно. На 7 не проверял. Оно основано на чтении /dev/proc псевдодиректории. Там достаточно информации для определения процесса. Но вручную работать сложновато, поэтому можно использовать уже написанную библиотеку 
https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses

Объединив с [ответом выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563131/182935) вы получите универсальное решение.

Comment: Не очень работает на 6-м, но можно придумать что-то.Эх жаль, на 5ке конечно классно все работало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

До Android 5 (Lollipop, API 21) можно было сделать так:

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

Начиная с `Android` 5 этот метод вернет только ваше приложение и `launcher`. Насколько мне известно, из соображений безопасности и приватности, в Android 5 больше никак не получится. Логично, что приложение не должно знать, какие приложения у меня запущены.

Comment: в для версий ниже нет подобных способов?

Comment: неужели нет способа получить хотя бы список процессов, так получится и запущенное приложение может определить

Comment: @AmirShabanov, для версий ниже я как раз и описал способ.

Comment: @AmirShabanov, способа получить список запущенных приложений (или процессов) начиная с android 5 нет.